# not able to push changes in smartgit.it shows merging in project folder

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push, git-pull, smartgit

I am using SmartGit and when I take a pull(merge and pull), it shows 'merging' on my project folder in repositories window and it is not allowing me to push my change.

Comment: Did you already try to commit the Merging state? You might have to resolve conflicts before. Also, please post a screenshot of the Repository view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a commit to actually perform the merge, so commit the merge result after solving potential conflicts and then you can push